# How to store custom emojis inside text in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In a web application, a first idea of storing a text message that contains a custom emoji is to save the link of the emoji within the text.

For example if the `Messages` collection has a `content` field, that field would contain the following when an emoji is saved within the text:

```
I am an example content with an emoji icon <img src='assets/emojis/custom-emoji.png'/>
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, and I would like to know what are the recommendations for this kind of situation.

Comment: I would store a symbolic representation of the emoji and map it to an image path further down the line e.g. at render time

Comment: That means that the mapping between the symbolic representation of the emoji and its path will be defined in the client side? i.e: Each time I want to display a message, I will look for symbols in the text, and once they are found, I will replace the symbols with their related images based on the path within the map. I hope I am getting it right :)

Comment: Yes, or if you have an API you could do it at the point of the API returning data (e.g. store map in server side config) if you prefer. Either way it will make updating image paths simple and not require data migration in the future, or refactor if you decide to make them theme-able (e.g. how phones allow skin tones).

Comment: It's a good approach, thanks :) If you like you can post it as an answer so I can accept it and make it visible to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing them in some symbolic way e.g. `{emoji:smileyface}`. This will allow you to update image paths without doing any data migration in the future. It will also allow you to do things like theming.

You can do the mapping in a variable on the client or server and at the point of retrieving data map symbol -> path.